# how to get data from api when it's limited to chunks of 200 per request using python

Tags: python, api, request

I'm trying to get data from API which content is stock availabilities. The return data is in JSON format. The API has several parameters such as:

- active - filters only the active sku in the nomenclature - if set to True
- have_availability - filters only stock with quantity > 0 - if set to True
- separateByLabel - if set to True returns the distinct sku lot for every sku
- limit - value which selects the number of return results, by default it is set to 200 (if not specified)
- offset - value which selects the starting row from which i can start requesting data - for example from 201 ...

My code is:

```
api = "https://..................................getAvailabilities?token=10d1f9ca0d1410aca045f67cb7a18e3e"
PARAMS = {"separateByLabel": "True", "have_availability": "True"}

req = requests.post(api, params=PARAMS)
data = req.json()
```

My return data is in JSON format and it is look like this:

```
[{'item_id': 17051,
  'quantity': 1,
  'sku': 'CL0140',
  'params': {'EXPIRATION': '2000-01-01'},
  'item_name': 'product 1 - 270 Tablets',
  'store_name': 'warehouse 1',
  'label': 0,
  'store_id': 4669078},
...}]

and so on
```

My problem is that the request always returns 200 records from 5000 +. No matter if i set 'limit': 1000 or more, ther return records are always 200 or less (if i set to 100 for example). I can get less, but can't retrieve the all records.

In general my goal is to create stock-report with all expiring goods for my sales team. When i get the full data i use Pandas to make my calculations and etc.

How can i get all the records from this API? I was thinking to implement something like generator custom function but don't know from where to start.

Comment: Is your question, how to use a generator to aggregate the results of several requests with different offsets to your API in order to return all the elements ?

Comment: You set the `offset` value to the beginning of the next chunk.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```py
def data_generator():
  for offset in range(0, max_offset, 200):
     results = # Do you request for 200 elements
     for result in results:
        yield result
```

Of course, this is only the general idea with code to start with